# Multiple database connections with POG

Tags: php, database, object

I've been using POG (PHP Object Generator - http://www.phpobjectgenerator.com/) in a project and i need to do multiple database connections.

In the configuration file, i only define one connection.

How can i use POG to connect to multiple databases?

thanks

Comment: After having a (very) quick look at that site, I'd say that you need to generate two objects, one for each database connection. However, that being said, I don't quite see the purpose of POG

Answer (score 1):

I use pog in several projects. Sometimes I change the database connection
during the same script execution. To perform this I add a new method to
Database class, called Reset and rewrite Connect method too. Class looks like something like this:

```
public class Database{
    //..
    static $database = null;
    public static function Connect()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$database) || is_null(self::$database))
        {
            self::$database = new Database();
        }
        return self::$database->connection;
    }

    public static function Reset()
    {
        mysql_close(self::$database->connection);
        unset(self::$database);
    }
}
```

//usage:

```
include('configuration.php');
// use pog with first database
Database::Reset();
include('other_configuration.php');
// use pog with another database
```

---

You may also consider sending your questions to php-object-generator@googlegroups.com

Have a nice day